# What is the difference between 'satisfied life' and 'satisfying life'?

Tags: meaning

I have found 'satisfying life' is more frequently used than 'satisfied life.'

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

'Satisfying' is a present participle and works as an adjective. 'Satisfied' is a past participle and functions as an adjective.

boiling- present participle, boiled- past participle

boiling water- Water is continuing to boil. boiled water- Water has been boiled.

satisfying life- Life is continuing to satisfy. satisfied life- Life has been satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at them, they both appear kind of the same.

But, a "satisfying life" means the person living that life is continually satisfied in that life as opposed to a "satisfied life" which indicates the life was satisfactory at one point of time but not so anymore.

Consider these examples.

1. "The money is good these days. I have a satisfying life".
2. "I have had a satisfied life. But after my dog died, it became hellish."